# New Rails App dies with Errno::EIO at /

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Any ideas why a freshly made rails app would fail right away with a completely unhelpful message?

(On Mac OS 10.6, Fresh install of RVM-head. rvm install ruby 1.9.2, gem install rails)
Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.5

Rails new myApp
cd myApp
rails server
Navigate to localhost:3000...

Application Error
Errno::EIO at /
Input/output error -

Comment: Is there anything in `dmesg(1)` output?

Comment: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x100002000): p=27069[ruby] clearing CS_VALID

Comment: The [code signing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH3-SW3) message looks unrelated, but it _might_ be an indicator that you've got bad memory or corrupted storage? Can you run something pretty memory and disk intensive, like some huge C/C++/Objective C builds for a while, and look for segfaults or bus errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of computer cleaning. Everything short of a reinstall. Now it works. I can only guess that poor computer maintenance (unused, half installed extensions / virtual devices / etc) was causing unpredictable havoc.

Comment: Installation and project build is so easy with the Rails stack I've saved considerable amounts of time wiping the install instead of trying to debug obscure configuration problems.  Hooray for repositories and bundler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows?  Your life will be hell unless you downgrade your Ruby environment to 1.8.7

Comment: Mac OS 10.6, Fresh install of RVM-head (Thanks, I updated my question with this info)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was starting rails server via the Aptana command line window. On a hunch I stopped it and ran rails server via the Windows command line and this got it working. It appears that Aptana isn't loading all the libraries like it should when run from its command windows.